# php mail() function not working using phpmailer

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
//echo !extension_loaded('openssl')?"Not Available":"Available <br/>";

$name = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$number = $_POST['phone'];
$profession = $_POST['profession'];

$to = 'example@gmail.com';
$subject = 'user registration';
$phone = "phone number:".$number;

$message = "client details:"."\n"."Name:".$name."\n"."email:".$email."\n"."phone number:".$number."\n"."profession:".$profession;

$headers = "From:".$email;

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               

$mail->isSMTP();                                      
$mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';      
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                            
$mail->Username = 'example@gmail.com';                      
$mail->Password = 'password';                           
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;

$mail->setFrom($email, $name);

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $message;

if($mail->send()) {
    header("Location: ../../thankyouNew.html");
}
else {
    header("Location: ../../somethingWrong.html");
}
```

?>

code is executing else block, i want to send mail to example@gmail.com and return user to the thankyou.html page after the mail function is executed.I am new to this php and i would highly appreciate the help thank you in advance.
forget the below lines........

Comment: what is in your php error log?

Comment: try to format ur question. we can hardly read it. and what do you mean by not working, does it give you an error or something?

Comment: try to check your error logs to see what error occur. Also add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` in your current code just after starting `<?php` and run code again and see if you got something.

Comment: Change your $mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';  to $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually specify where you want to send the email. You need to use the `addAddress()` method, as shown below. This method requires one parameter, but you may supply two - in the same way your `setFrom()` method has; first the target address, then an optional display name.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

// ...

$mail->setFrom($email, $name);
$mail->addAddress($to); // Add this method to specify a recipient 
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $message;
if($mail->send()) {
    // ...
}
// ...
```

Comment: i did it but still not receiving the mail, do i need to configure anything in the server before this

Comment: Alright, then the problem isn't an obvious one. So, instead of guessing back and forth - we'll get the actual error-message from PHPMailer. Add `echo  $mail->ErrorInfo;` in the `else` block. If that don't give you anything, set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` after creating the object somewhere and add `$mail->Debugoutput = function($str, $level) { echo "De-bug: $level; message: $str"; };` in the else-block